# What am I doing wrong? featuretools' performance estimation seems to be abnormal

Tags: featuretools

I was just trying to run the [Featuretools demo](https://github.com/Featuretools/predict-loan-repayment) on my Windows 10 machine with 64GB of RAM

However, it says that the feature generation will take 800 hours! Is this normal?

See issue I have raised in Featuretools

https://github.com/Featuretools/predict-loan-repayment/issues/3

Is it because Windows isn't well supported?

Comment: this is a complicated dataset and you're creating many features. take a look at this blog post: https://blog.featurelabs.com/scaling-featuretools-with-dask-2/ and this notebook: https://github.com/Featuretools/predict-loan-repayment/blob/master/Automated%20Loan%20Repayment.ipynb

Comment: I am just running the code in the notebook. I also tried `import dask.dataframe as pd`. So should I expect to see what I expected though? What machine do I need to run the notebook in a reasonable time?